# Bluetooth as a virtual audio device (input)

Tags: pi-3, audio, bluetooth, input-device, pulseaudio

I am trying to setup this `audio-reactive-led-strip` library but with Bluetooth audio as the input. I have so far, got my LED strip to work with the standard `strandtest.py` and have also successfully setup Bluetooth audio to play on the Pi (I have it outputting through the 3.5mm audio jack).

Now, it states on the audio-reactive documentation that it supports a "virtual audio device" and as such I believe I need to set it to listen to a Bluetooth virtual audio device, but I am unsure of how to go about this - https://github.com/scottlawsonbc/audio-reactive-led-strip#virtual-audio-source.

Here is my current output from running said library's script:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python audio-reactive-led-strip/python/visualization.py
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4996:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4996:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
No audio input. Volume below threshold. Volume: 9.97921e-17
No audio input. Volume below threshold. Volume: 0.0
```

Thanks in advance!